# Parameter as reference?

Tags: bash

I am trying to make a function swap() like this

```
swap(){
#swap $1 and $2 here
}
```

What I want to swap is an array let say we have

```
array[0]=12
array[1]=45
array[2]=99

swap $array[0] $array[1]
```

So I want to swap array[0] so it becomes 45 and array[1] becomes 12 after the swap function. I was thinking of doing this swapping by referencing $array[0] (such as pointer in c) and $array[1] so it could be changed.
I found command eval and upvar but seriously, I don't understand a thing. I am pretty new with this shell scripting and most of the documentation out there confused me a lot.

Comment: What shell are you using?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken.. umm.. when I use echo $SHELL it turns out /bin/bash.. when I did ps -p $$ , it is PID 2627 TTY pts/0 TIME 00:00:00 CMD bash.. And my bash version is version 4.2

Answer (score 0):

`bash` arrays are a little tricky. The clearest thing you can do is to write the function to take *three* arguments, the array name and the two indices to swap. This also requires that you treat `array` as a global variable; you simply cannot pass an entire array as a single object in `bash`.

(This does require `bash` 4 or later, which introduced the `-g` flag to `declare`.)

```
swap () {
    local name=$1
    local a=$2
    local b=$3

    local aname=$name[$a]
    local bname=$name[$b]
    local tmp=${!aname}    # e.g. tmp=${array[$a]}
    declare -g "${aname}=${!bname}"   # e.g. array[$a]=${array[$b]}
    declare -g "${bname}=$tmp"        # e.g. array[$b]=$tmp
}
```

`bash` 4.3 introduces namerefs `(declare -n)` which simplify this greatly by letting you declare a local array that acts as an alias for the global array.

```
swap () {
  declare -n arr=$1
  local a=$2 b=$3
  local tmp=${arr[$a]}
  arr[$a]=${arr[$b]}
  arr[$b]=$tmp
```

}